# how to do a task conditionally using celery?

Tags: python, celery

I have a celery task queue like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from proj.celery import app


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


@app.task
def mul(x, y):
    return x * y


@app.task
def xsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```

Now i want to call the 3rd task `xsum` if and only if both the other two tasks `add` and `mul` succeeded properly. How can i do this using celery??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use some canvas like `chain` or `chord` [(read the docs)](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html). Basically, a `chain` executes all its tasks in sequential order and a `chord` is made of one header (= a group of tasks) and one callback (= a final task) that will be executed once the group has finished. For instance, you could do something like:

```
callback = xsum.s()
header = [add.s(1, 1), mul.s(2, 2)]
result = chord(header)(callback)
result.get()
```

About how the errors are handled, I'll just quote the docs:

> From 3.1 errors will propagate to the callback, so the callback will
>   not be executed instead the callback changes to failure state, and the
>   error is set to the ChordError exception:
>
> If you’re running 3.0.14 or later you can enable the new behavior via
>   the CELERY_CHORD_PROPAGATES setting:
>
> CELERY_CHORD_PROPAGATES = True

Answer (score 0):

You have to [store results](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results) and [check](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html) them in the `xsum` function.